# Difference using avr-gcc and avr-ld in ELF (Executable and Linkable Format) file generation

Tags: c, gcc, linker, microcontroller, avr

Sorry if this might be off-topic.
In the process of generating .hex(Intel HEX format) files using avr-gcc or avr-ld the output(final result) is significantly different. As an minimal clarification I am talking about the step of generating ELF file just after generating the Object files.

On my first attempt, I used `avr-ld` to generate my ELF file. Process works smoothly but after generating HEX files and uploading to my board it did nothing (as in uploading an blank HEX file).

On my second try, I followed the advice found [here](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__demo__project_1demo_project_compile.html):

> It is important to specify the MCU type when linking. The compiler uses the -mmcu option to choose start-up files and run-time libraries that get linked together. If this option isn't specified, the compiler defaults to the 8515 processor environment, which is most certainly what you didn't want.

It did as I expected. Uploaded the HEX file and my board updated accordingly.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Why did the linker (`avr-ld`) lose information about the micro-controller I am using. I thought that the MCU information is stored in the Object files.
2. What is the logic behind this configuration? Is my way of thinking wrong (in using `avr-gcc` for compilation/generating .o files, `avr-ld` to link the .o files and generate the EFL files, and `avr-objcopy` to strip only usefull information and changing the format of the file ELF -> HEX)?
3. Is any way in achieving the same output using `avr-ld` as when using `avr-gcc` for generating my ELF file?

Comment: gcc calls ld to do the linking unless you tell it not to (-c or -S) so it is a matter of what your ld command line is when used directly vs what gcc passes to it.  A quick and dirty way of seeing this is to rename your avr-ld program and replace it with one that prints out the command line, there may be other ways to do it, but that is one.   and yes objcopy gets you from the native binary format to other binary formats (or from one to another).

Comment: Could you add the commands you used in your two attempts? Otherwise it's hard to say what you did differently. avr-gcc links with avr-ld in any case.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why did the linker (avr-ld) lose information about the micro-controller I am using. I thought that the MCU information is stored in the Object files.

The linker doesn't lose that information, it was never supplied in the first place.  Object files resp. ELF headers are on level of "emulation", i.e. granularity like `-mmcu=arch` where `arch` is one of `avr2`, `avr25`, `avrxmega2`, `avrtiny` etc.

> 2. using `avr-gcc` for compilation/generating .o files, `avr-ld` to link the .o files and generate the ELF files, and `avr-objcopy` to strip only usefull information and changing the format of the file ELF → HEX?

**`avr-gcc` is not a compiler, it's just a driver program** that calls other programs like compiler proper `cc1` or `cc1plus`, assembler `as`, linker `ld` depending on file type and options provided.  The driver will add options to these programs which greatly simplifies their usage, many of which are described in `specs-attiny25` (since v5 onwards).

As an example, take a simple `main.c` with a main function returning 0, and process it with

`avr-gcc main.c -o main.elf -mmcu=attiny25 -save-temps -v -Wl,-v`

The `-v` makes the driver show the commands it is issuing, and `-save-temps` stores intermediate files like assembly.  For avr-gcc v8.5, the link process starts with a call of `collect2`:

```
.../bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/8.5.0/collect2 -plugin .../bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/8.5.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=.../bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/8.5.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=main.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lm -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lattiny25 -mavr25 -o main.elf .../bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack/crtattiny25.o -L.../bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/avr25/tiny-stack -L.../bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack -L.../bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0 -L.../bin/../lib/gcc -L.../bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/lib main.o -v --start-group -lgcc -lm -lc -lattiny25 --end-group
```

where `...` stands for the absolute path where the tools are installed. As you can see, the driver adds some salt, for example it links against startup code `crtattiny25.o`, standard libs like `libc.a`, `libm.a`, `libgcc.a`.  `collect2` gathers some extra information needed to build startup code, and then calls back the compiler<sup>1</sup> and finally `ld`.

The options provided to `ld` look very much like the ones provided to `collect2`. The only device-specific stuff is: startup code `crtattiny25.o` and device lib `libattiny25.a`.  Many other device-specific stuff has already been compiler into the code, like SFR addresses, `#ifdef __AVR_ATtiny25__` etc.

> 3. Is any way in achieving the same output using `avr-ld` as when using `avr-gcc` for generating my ELF file?

You could provide all that options by hand.

---

<sup>1</sup>Calling back the compiler is needed for LTO (link-time optimization) as of `-flto`.  The linker calls a plugin which calls the compiler with LTO byte-code, compiles it to assemblwith the LTO-compiler `lto1`, then `as`, then `ld`.  Newer versions of the tool are always using linker plugin when without lto compilation; one can `-fno-use-linker-plugin` which makes the call chain and options somewhat simpler.